# Windows could not start DBConsole for new database instance

Tags: windows, oracle, oracle11g

I am getting this error:

> Windows could not start the OracleDBConsoleOracleInstance2 on Local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the system vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1

I installed Oracle 11g on Windows 7 and created my 1st database instance (oracleInstance1) successfully with a listener and service configured. I could access this database using DBconsole URL: `https://localhost:1158/em`.

I see the services started for:

- `OracleDBConsoleOracleInstance1`
- `OracleOraDb11g_home1TNSListener`
- `OracleServiceOracleInstance1`

Next, I created a second database instance (`oracleInstance2`) and have configured a new service for this database. I am using the same listener as I intend to use one database instance at any point of time.

However, I got this warning message during configuration:

```
Enterprise manager configuration succeeded with the following warning - Error starting Database Control. Please execute the following command(s).
  1. Set the environment variable ORACLE_UNQNAME to Database unique name.
  2. C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\emctl.bat start dbconsole
```

To start the new database console, I stopped the previously running DBConsole, OracleDBConsoleOracle1 and started the new DBConsole OracleDBConsoleOracle2 and get the above error.

When I try to start dbconsole manually using `emctl dbconsole start`, it starts OracleDBConsoleOracle1 instead.

I changed environment variables `ORACLE_SID=oracle2` and `ORACLE_UNQNAME=oracle2`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are there more details in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your env vars are applied correctly? If you set them in a DOS window then they'll only be visible there, you need to set them in the windows 'environment variables' screen.